# proper link formatting

Tags: php, html

I am trying to create a link, which will, allow my paginated search to go onto the next page of results including the search term in the url

I get the following error with the link I have created

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in /home/dd615/public_html/searchPage.php on line 47

here is the link

```
echo "<a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?search=$_GET['search']?pagenumber=1'> FIRST </a>";
```

any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap the second variable as well:

```
echo "<a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?search={$_GET['search']}&pagenumber=1'> FIRST </a>";
```

But it would be better to use proper encoding. So try this:

```
echo '<a href="' . htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?search='.urlencode($_GET['search']).'&pagenumber=1') . '"> FIRST </a>';
```

[`urlencode`](http://php.net/urlencode) is used to encode any character that is inappropriate in a URL query (according to the [*application/x-www-form-urlencoded* type](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.1)) and [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) escapes the HTML special characters.

Answer (score 0):

it's because of special string syntax. You encloded in curly braces $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] but failed to do the same for the $_GET['search'].
Refer to the [string syntax manual page](http://php.net/types.string), it worth reading

Also note that only one `?` character can be in the query string, `&` should be used as a separator for the rest of the string

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your actual question is that you need you put curly brackets around $_GET['search'] because it's inside of those quotes. So like this:

```
echo "<a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?search={$_GET['search']}?pagenumber=1'> FIRST </a>";
```

Also, unrelated to your question, you may want to change the second '?' to '&' like so:

```
echo "<a href='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}?search={$_GET['search']}&pagenumber=1'> FIRST </a>";
```

But then again, maybe not.